# Separation property of general uninform graph search from Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach Textbook by Peter Norvig and Stuart J. Russell

Tags: proofs, norvig-russell

Before I start, I'm deeply sorry if my grammar is incorrect or hard to understand, since I haven't trained my English for a long time. Thanks you for spending time and effort to read and answer my question.

I'm trying to understand the solution for exercise 3.13 of Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach Textbook by Peter Norvig and Stuart J. Russell. However, the author's solution from his solution manual has a lot of ideas that are unclear to me. So please help we to correct my understanding and explain what the author really means in his solution.

---

### The exercise 3.13

The GRAPH-SEARCH algorithm has another nice property: the frontier separates the state-space graph into the explored region and the unexplored region, so that every path from the initial state to an unexplored state has to pass through a state in the frontier. Prove that GRAPH-SEARCH satisfies the graph separation property.

Here is the GRAPH-SEARCH algorithm:

```
function GRAPH-SEARCH(problem) returns a solution, or failure
  initialize the frontier using the initial state of problem
  initialize the explored set to be empty
  loop do
    if the frontier is empty then return failure
    choose a leaf node and remove it from the frontier
    if the node contains a goal state then return the corresponding solution
    add the node to the explored set
    expand the chosen node, adding the resulting nodes to the frontier
      only if not in the frontier or explored set
```

---

### The solution from solution manual

At the start of the search, the frontier holds the initial state; hence, trivially, every path from the initial state to an unexplored state includes a node in the frontier (the initial state itself).

Now, we assume that the property holds at the beginning of an arbitrary iteration of the GRAPH-SEARCH algorithm in Figure 3.7. We assume that the iteration completes, i.e., the frontier is not empty and the selected leaf node n is not a goal state. At the end of the iteration, n has been removed from the frontier and its successors (if not already explored or in the frontier) placed in the frontier. Consider any path from the initial state to an unexplored state; by the induction hypothesis such a path (at the beginning of the iteration) includes at least one frontier node; except when n is the only such node, the separation property automatically holds. Hence, we focus on paths passing through n (and no other frontier node). By definition, the next node n′ along the path from n must be a successor of n that (by the preceding sentence) is already not in the frontier. Furthermore, n′ cannot be in the explored set, since by assumption there is a path from n′ to an unexplored node not passing through the frontier, which would violate the separation property as every explored node is connected to the initial state by explored nodes (see lemma below for proof this is always possible). Hence, n′ is not in the explored set, hence it will be added to the frontier; then the path will include a frontier node and the separation property is restored.

Lemma: Every explored node is connected to the initial state by a path of explored nodes.

Proof: This is true initially, since the initial state is connected to itself. Since we never remove nodes from the explored region, we only need to check new nodes we add to the explored list on an expansion. Let n be such a new explored node. This is previously on the frontier, so it is a neighbor of a node n′ previously explored (i.e., its parent). n′ is, by hypothesis is connected to the initial state by a path of explored nodes. This path with n appended is a path of explored nodes connecting n′ to the initial state.

---

### My understanding about the solution

1. "We assume that the iteration completes, i.e., the frontier is not empty and the selected leaf node n is not a goal state". The author means the arbitrary iteration that he assumes to hold the property, which when completes will not lead to end of loop.
2. "By definition, the next node n′ along the path from n must be a successor of n that (by the preceding sentence) is already not in the frontier". The author means at the end of the iteration, a new node n' will be added to the search tree with the Parent pointer pointing to node n.
3. "By definition, the next node n′ along the path from n must be a successor of n that (by the preceding sentence) is already not in the frontier. Furthermore, n′ cannot be in the explored set, since by assumption there is a path from n′ to an unexplored node not passing through the frontier, which would violate the separation property as every explored node is connected to the initial state by explored nodes (see lemma below for proof this is always possible). Hence, n′ is not in the explored set, hence it will be added to the frontier; then the path will include a frontier node and the separation property is restored". Here, the author is trying to prove that n' must be added to the frontier by proving that n' cannot already be at the frontier nor in the explored set. However, if n' is added to search tree as successor of node n, then n' mustn't be in explored set or already at frontier. So why did the author has to reprove n'?
4. "Furthermore, n′ cannot be in the explored set, since by assumption there is a path from n′ to an unexplored node not passing through the frontier, which would violate the separation property as every explored node is connected to the initial state by explored nodes". How does this help proving n' isn't in explored set?

---

Deeply thank for your answers and replies.

Comment: This post seems to contain multiple questions and seems to be unnecessary long. Can you please edit the post to leave just one question and move the others to a different post? Also, please, put your question in the title. "Separation property..." is not a question.